# Daisy chaining of multiple blocs of 4x(8x8) MAX7219 matrix

Tags: arduino-uno, max7219

Thanks for your presentation https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tags/max7219/info.
You say that multiple MAX7219 8x8 blocs can easily be daisy-chained and you show an example of at least 12 blocs displaying "Testing12345".
Trying several programs I found for Arduino, I never succeeded to chain more than 8 blocs with 8x8 matrix (either 8 individual blocs or 2 groups of 4 as on your image).
So I'ld be very happy if you send me examples of programs managing more than 8 blocs for fixed or scrolling displays.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The person who wrote the presentation will probably not see this... I suggest you make this question more 'generic'  (not using 'you' ), and add a comment in his post to mention yours (since it's a new question).

Comment: `I never succeeded to chain more than 8 blocs with 8x8 matrix` is a useless description of the problem because it contains no information that can be used to resolve the problem .... something like `if i chain more than 8 blocs, then XYX happens` is way more useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @Majenko 's MAX libary https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_MAX72XX .  It allows you to specify how many modules are to be addressed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very intersting library. But, with its examples, there is an addressing issue on my display. For each 8x8 matrix the columns seem to be inverted, displaying first the column #8 instead of column #1. So the global scrolling is OK from right to left (first to last matrix of the daisy-chain), but each matrix is scrolling its columns from left to right with inverted display!

Comment: With static display of a text, it's the same: the columns of each 8x8 matrix are inverted.

Answer (score 1):

All is OK changing the proposed statement

## define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::PAROLA_HW

to

## define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW